# android studio shows the install successful but it gives error while lunching physical device

Tags: android

Install successfully finished in 14 s 642 ms.
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices

i restart the android studio and run it again